# UITableView with UIScrollView iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, uiscrollview

I am developing an iOS Xamarin app which shows a list of items. Right now Iam using a UITableViewController to show all the items. But my requirement is to show about 4 items on first screen and swipe/flip to see the next 4 items and so on till the list of items finish. Iam using a Storyboard right now.

I didnt not find any documentation on the same. Can anyone give me a reference on how to achieve it?

Comment: It's better to use a `UICollectionView` instead.

Comment: @Raptor Could you please provide me with an example. Iam new to iOS and xamarin

Comment: go search `UICollectionView` tutorials in Google. You'll definitely find a lot results